# how to use chunk in blade in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

i am trying to use chunk method in laravel to show my data in the blade but I get it empty

here is my code

```
$accounts = Acc_account::where('cat', 2)->chunk(200, function (account) {
            foreach ($accounts as $account) {
                //
            }
        }); ;
```

and here is my code in blade

```
@foreach ($accounts as $item)
@endforeach
```

Comment: how do you display this in blade? Did you properly return the `$accounts`?

Comment: are you returning this in your blade file?

Comment: yes i do using foreach in blade for $accounts @Mr.Kenneth

Comment: @MitKathrotia yes i do

Comment: @Shady Hesham please check this sloution is work for you ??

Comment: @ShadyHesham please check

Comment: Why are you using chunk()? are you processing anything inside that for each?

Comment: What is the goal?  Do you want to break up a large number of results so eg you don't hit memory limits?  That's what [the query builder `chunk()` is usually used for](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#chunking-results). Or are you trying to generate sets of results that you can use in grids or rows in your views?  That's what [the Collection method `chunk()` is usually used for](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-chunk).  My guess is maybe you want the Collection method, since chunking the query and then returning the full result set anyway doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$accounts = [];
Acc_account::where('cat', 2)->chunk(200, function ($chunkedAccounts) use (&$accounts) {
    foreach ($chunkedAccounts as $account) {
        $accounts[] = $account;
    }
});
return view('your.blade.view', compact('accounts'));
```

Comment: Please never post "try this" / code-only answers on Stack Overflow -- this is the least generous form of volunteerism on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `paginate()`, in case of listing records in blade file.

In controller,

```
$accounts = Acc_account::where('cat', 2)->paginate(50); // 50 items per page

return view('accounts.index', compact('accounts'));
```

In blade file,

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Account List</h1>
        
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($accounts as $account)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $account->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $account->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $account->balance }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        {{ $accounts->links() }} <!-- This will display pagination links -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Would you like to show a bit more generosity by demonstrating the implementation or would you like to convert this "hint" to a comment under the question?